# Send php autorization post request

Tags: php, curl

Im tryint to send this curl:

```
 curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" --data-urlencode "model=" --data-urlencode "url=http://assets.mojang.com/SkinTemplates/steve.png" https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/<uuid>/skin
```

I tried:

```
 $url = 'https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/myuuid/skin';
 $skin_url = "http://assets.mojang.com/SkinTemplates/steve.png";
 $accesstoken = "myacessToken";
 $crl = curl_init();
 $headr = array();

 $headr[] = 'Host: api.mojang.com';
 $headr[] = 'User-Agent: curl/7.49.0';
 $headr[] = 'Accept: */*';
 $headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accesstoken;
 $headr[] = 'Content-Length: 69';
 $headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

 $ch = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
     "model=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fassets.mojang.com%2FSkinTemplates%2Fsteve.png");

 $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
 var_dump($server_output);
 curl_close ($ch);
```

My output:

```
   bool(false)
```

Im sure that my access token is valid and uuid. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Could you show us `https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/myuuid/skin` code?

Comment: Its the Mojang API, u can look at http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Change_Skin

Comment: Try with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);`

Comment: It works, thanks!!

Comment: added as response ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);`